# How to limit a slideshow in size (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, resize

I am a beginner trying to learn front-end development. I often look at other code and try to adapt it. I found this amazing slideshow which I wanted to try out:

https://codepen.io/supah/pen/zZaPeE

I formatted the scss to css via an online tool, imported every script necessary and the slideshow works great!

But it's in fullscreen. **How do I limit it in size?** Let's say I want this slideshow to appear on my homepage, beneath the nav, in the size of 600w x 400h.

I tried:

- Adding another div at the top of the slideshow, styling it accordingly with height and width
- Styling the "split-slideshow" with height and width
- Changing all height and width in the css code from 100vh/vw to e.g. 50vh/vw

NOTHING seems to work. The only thing that happens is that the images inside the slideshow shrink in size and appear in the top left corner of the screen. Navigation, the "area of functionality" etc. stays the same (full width, full height).

When changing the window size, the slideshow scales amazingly well and fits all conditions, be it a quadratic window, a wide window etc. There surely must be a way to "trap" it in a certain size?

(Sorry for including all the code - I really don't know what the minimum is to understand the problem)

Here is the same code, formatted from scss to css etc., which I am running locally:

https://jsfiddle.net/by37cuwz/1/

Code:

```
HTML
<!--

This code (HTML, CSS, JS) was created by Fabio Ottaviani. View the original here: https://codepen.io/supah/pen/zZaPeE

-->
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slideshow.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:100">
</head>

<body>
  <!--

  Follow me on
  Dribbble: https://dribbble.com/supahfunk
  Twitter: https://twitter.com/supahfunk
  Codepen: https://codepen.io/supah/

  -->
  <div class="split-slideshow">
    <div class="slideshow">
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/master/canyon-2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/master/canyon-3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/master/canyon-4.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/master/canyon-1.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-text">
      <div class="item">Canyon</div>
      <div class="item">Desert</div>
      <div class="item">Erosion</div>
      <div class="item">Shape</div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```
CSS
body, html {
     height: 100%;
     background: #110101;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .slideshow {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 1;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .slideshow .slider {
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vw;
     z-index: 2;
}
 .slideshow .slider * {
     outline: none;
}
 .slideshow .slider .item {
     height: 100vh;
     width: 100vw;
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
     border: none;
}
 .slideshow .slider .item .text {
     display: none;
}
 .slideshow .slider .item img {
     min-width: 101%;
     min-height: 101%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
 .slideshow .slick-dots {
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 100;
     width: 40px;
     height: auto;
     bottom: auto;
     top: 50%;
     right: 0;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     left: auto;
     color: #fff;
     display: block;
}
 .slideshow .slick-dots li {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
}
 .slideshow .slick-dots li button {
     position: relative;
     width: 20px;
     height: 15px;
     text-align: center;
}
 .slideshow .slick-dots li button:before {
     content: '';
     background: #fff;
     color: #fff;
     height: 2px;
     width: 20px;
     border-radius: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     right: 0;
     left: auto;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
     opacity: 0.6;
}
 .slideshow .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
     width: 40px;
     opacity: 1;
}
 .slideshow.slideshow-right {
     left: 0;
     z-index: 1;
     width: 50vw;
     pointer-events: none;
}
 .slideshow.slideshow-right .slider {
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;
}
 .slideshow-text {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
   margin-top: 50vh;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     z-index: 100;
     font-size: 80px;
     width: 100vw;
     text-align: center;
     color: #fff;
     font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 100;
     pointer-events: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     letter-spacing: 20px;
     line-height: 0.8;
}
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
     .slideshow-text {
         font-size: 40px;
    }
}
 .the-most {
     position: fixed;
     z-index: 1;
     bottom: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 50vw;
     max-width: 200px;
     padding: 10px;
}
 .the-most img {
     max-width: 100%;
}
```

```
JS
var $slider = $('.slideshow .slider'),
  maxItems = $('.item', $slider).length,
  dragging = true,
  tracking,
  rightTracking;

$sliderRight = $('.slideshow').clone().addClass('slideshow-right').appendTo($('.split-slideshow'));

rightItems = $('.item', $sliderRight).toArray();
reverseItems = rightItems.reverse();
$('.slider', $sliderRight).html('');
for (i = 0; i < maxItems; i++) {
  $(reverseItems[i]).appendTo($('.slider', $sliderRight));
}

$slider.addClass('slideshow-left');
$('.slideshow-left').slick({
  vertical: true,
  verticalSwiping: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  dots: true,
  speed: 1000,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)'
}).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  if (currentSlide > nextSlide && nextSlide == 0 && currentSlide == maxItems - 1) {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', -1);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems);
  } else if (currentSlide < nextSlide && currentSlide == 0 && nextSlide == maxItems - 1) {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', -1);
  } else {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems - 1 - nextSlide);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', nextSlide);
  }
}).on("mousewheel", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.deltaX > 0 || event.deltaY < 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  } else if (event.deltaX < 0 || event.deltaY > 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  };
}).on('mousedown touchstart', function(){
  dragging = true;
  tracking = $('.slick-track', $slider).css('transform');
  tracking = parseInt(tracking.split(',')[5]);
  rightTracking = $('.slideshow-right .slick-track').css('transform');
  rightTracking = parseInt(rightTracking.split(',')[5]);
}).on('mousemove touchmove', function(){
  if (dragging) {
    newTracking = $('.slideshow-left .slick-track').css('transform');
    newTracking = parseInt(newTracking.split(',')[5]);
    diffTracking = newTracking - tracking;
    $('.slideshow-right .slick-track').css({'transform': 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ' + (rightTracking - diffTracking) + ')'});
  }
}).on('mouseleave touchend mouseup', function(){
  dragging = false;
});

$('.slideshow-right .slider').slick({
  swipe: false,
  vertical: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 950,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)',
  initialSlide: maxItems - 1
});
$('.slideshow-text').slick({
  swipe: false,
  vertical: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 900,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)'
});
```

Comment: Let me know if my answer is missing anything you needed, if not, then please mark my answer as the correct solution to your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forked the fiddle and edited the code to achieve what I think you are wanting.

The key to this was to add max-widths and max-height to the "split-slideshow" element. Then to make all of the inherited width and heights of the children to percentages instead of vh and vw. I also had to change some other minor styling to make sure it all lines up.

Here is the JS Fiddle as well as the code below. Let me know if you have any other questions.

https://jsfiddle.net/mo15wht8/2/

```js
var $slider = $('.slideshow .slider'),
  maxItems = $('.item', $slider).length,
  dragging = true,
  tracking,
  rightTracking;

$sliderRight = $('.slideshow').clone().addClass('slideshow-right').appendTo($('.split-slideshow'));

rightItems = $('.item', $sliderRight).toArray();
reverseItems = rightItems.reverse();
$('.slider', $sliderRight).html('');
for (i = 0; i < maxItems; i++) {
  $(reverseItems[i]).appendTo($('.slider', $sliderRight));
}

$slider.addClass('slideshow-left');
$('.slideshow-left').slick({
  vertical: true,
  verticalSwiping: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  dots: true,
  speed: 1000,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)'
}).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  if (currentSlide > nextSlide && nextSlide == 0 && currentSlide == maxItems - 1) {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', -1);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems);
  } else if (currentSlide < nextSlide && currentSlide == 0 && nextSlide == maxItems - 1) {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', -1);
  } else {
    $('.slideshow-right .slider').slick('slickGoTo', maxItems - 1 - nextSlide);
    console.log(nextSlide);
    $('.slideshow-text').slick('slickGoTo', nextSlide);
  }
}).on("mousewheel", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (event.deltaX > 0 || event.deltaY < 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  } else if (event.deltaX < 0 || event.deltaY > 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  };
}).on('mousedown touchstart', function(){
  dragging = true;
  tracking = $('.slick-track', $slider).css('transform');
  tracking = parseInt(tracking.split(',')[5]);
  rightTracking = $('.slideshow-right .slick-track').css('transform');
  rightTracking = parseInt(rightTracking.split(',')[5]);
}).on('mousemove touchmove', function(){
  if (dragging) {
    newTracking = $('.slideshow-left .slick-track').css('transform');
    newTracking = parseInt(newTracking.split(',')[5]);
    diffTracking = newTracking - tracking;
    $('.slideshow-right .slick-track').css({'transform': 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ' + (rightTracking - diffTracking) + ')'});
  }
}).on('mouseleave touchend mouseup', function(){
  dragging = false;
});

$('.slideshow-right .slider').slick({
  swipe: false,
  vertical: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 950,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1)',
  initialSlide: maxItems - 1
});
$('.slideshow-text').slick({
  swipe: false,
  vertical: true,
  arrows: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 900,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, .9)'
});
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #110101;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.split-slideshow{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 .slideshow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 .slideshow .slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
 .slideshow .slider * {
  outline: none;
}
 .slideshow .slider .item {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}
 .slideshow .slider .item .text {
  display: none;
}
 .slideshow .slider .item img {
  min-width: 101%;
  min-height: 101%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(-25%, -25%);
}
 .slideshow .slick-dots {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  width: 40px;
  height: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  left: auto;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
 .slideshow .slick-dots li {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
 .slideshow .slick-dots li button {
  position: relative;
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
 .slideshow .slick-dots li button:before {
  content: '';
  background: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  height: 2px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
 .slideshow .slick-dots li.slick-active button:before {
  width: 40px;
  opacity: 1;
}
 .slideshow.slideshow-right {
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
 .slideshow.slideshow-right .slider {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
 .slideshow-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  pointer-events: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 20px;
  line-height: 0.9;
}
 @media (max-width: 767px) {
  .slideshow-text {
   font-size: 40px;
 }
}
 .the-most {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 10px;
}
 .the-most img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!--

This code (HTML, CSS, JS) was created by Fabio Ottaviani. View the original here: https://codepen.io/supah/pen/zZaPeE

-->
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slideshow.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:100">
</head>

<body>
  <!--

  Follow me on
  Dribbble: https://dribbble.com/supahfunk
  Twitter: https://twitter.com/supahfunk
  Codepen: https://codepen.io/supah/

  -->
  <div class="split-slideshow">
    <div class="slideshow">
      <div class="slider">
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/master/canyon-2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/master/canyon-3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/master/canyon-4.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supahfunk/supah-codepen/master/canyon-1.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow-text">
      <div class="item">Canyon</div>
      <div class="item">Desert</div>
      <div class="item">Erosion</div>
      <div class="item">Shape</div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.12/jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I tried to achieve.

Could I ask you why the height and width styles had to be changed from vh/vw to percentage?

Does view height/view width always apply to the resolution of the screen/browser window?

Comment: Although, there is a problem with this solution. While the size is limited properly now, the images don't line up anymore. Now the same image is being displayed on the left and right side. Before it was oen image spit in two halves. 

And I realized that changing the max-width/height also causes teh script to split the image not in 50/50 but something like 30/70.

Do you perhaps know what causes this?

Comment: Answer to your first question: yes the vh and vw apply to screen view area. I changed to percentages so that it ould inherit from the hard set dimension you set for the top element.

Comment: @Lukasz I also fixed the code so that the two bugs you were noticing are no longer occurring. You should be able to just change the max-width and max-height on the parent element and everything else will cascade accordingly. The places you should mess around with to see how I fixed it are the ".slideshow.slideshow-right"  CSS block and the ".slideshow .slider .item img" CSS block. Particularly experiment with the transform. It will bring clarity to how this effect was created. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thank you so much! Also for directing me. I will definitly mess with those parameters and hopefully understand it one day. You're a saint.